# How to use derived parameter in an overriding function without dynamic casting

Tags: c++, parameters, polymorphism, overriding

Can anyone let me know how to achieve:

- the parameter of a method of a derived class being the parameter's
  derived class (not the parameter's base class)?

This is what I want:

```
class Base{
public:
    // Base class method has ParameterBase parameter
    virtual void f(ParameterBase pb) = 0;
}

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    // I want: Derived class method has ParameterDerived parameter;
    void f(ParameterDerived pd){ //do something with pd; }
}

class ParameterBase{
    // Base class of parameter;
}

class ParameterDerived : public ParameterBase{
    // Derived class of parameter;
}
```

How to achieve above?
Do I have to use ParamterBase in the derived method's parameter list and dynamic_cast the parameter in the method body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are asking for is called parameter type contra-variance. And C++ unfortunately, doesn't support it. C++ supports just the return type covariance. [See](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/20/covariance-and-contravariance/) here for a nice explanation.

> Perhaps inconveniently, C++ does not permit us to write the function
>   marked hmm... above. C++’s classical OOP system supports “covariant
>   return types,” but it does not support “contravariant parameter
>   types.”

But you can use `dynamic_cast<>()` operator. But first, you must change the parameter type to pointer or reference, and add at least one virtual member (virtual destructor counts too) to your `class ParameterBase` to make compiler to create virtual method table for it. Here is the code with references. Pointers can be used instead.

```
class ParameterBase
{
    public:
        // To make compiler to create virtual method table.
        virtual ~ParameterBase()
        {}
};

class ParameterDerived : public ParameterBase
{
};


class Base
{
    public:
        // Pointers or references should be used here.
        virtual void f(const ParameterBase& pb) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void f(const ParameterBase& pb) override
        {
            // And here is the casting.
            const ParameterDerived& pd=dynamic_cast<const ParameterDerived&>(pb);

        }
};


int main()
{
    Derived d;
    ParameterDerived p;

    d.f(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want Derived to be called with ParameterDerived, but you also want to declare the interface in abstract base classes.

The interface MUST have the same parameter types, but you can still enforce the right parameter subclass with a dynamic_cast inside Derived::f

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// interface
struct ParameterBase {
    virtual ~ParameterBase() {};
};

struct Base {
    virtual void f(ParameterBase *pb) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

// specific
struct ParameterDerived : public ParameterBase {
    std::string name;
    ParameterDerived(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}
    ParameterDerived& operator=(const ParameterDerived& rhs) { name = rhs.name; }
    ~ParameterDerived() {};
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived(){}
    Derived& operator=(const Derived &rhs) {}
    virtual ~Derived(){}

    void f(ParameterBase *pb) {
        ParameterDerived *pd = dynamic_cast<ParameterDerived*>(pb);
        if (pd) {
            std::cout << "Derived object with derived parameter " << pd->name << std::endl;
        } // else {throw std::exception("wrong parameter type");}
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived object;
    ParameterDerived param("foo");
    object.f(&param);
}
```